# Fill values from one dataframe to another with matching IDs

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas data frames, I want to get the sum of items_bought for each ID in DF1. Then add a column to DF2 containing the sum of items_bought calculated from DF1 with matching ID else fill it with 0. How can I do this in an elegant and efficient manner?

DF1

```
ID | items_bought
1        5
3        8
2        2
3        5
4        6
2        2
```

DF2

```
ID
1
2
8
3
2
```

Desired Result: DF2 Becomes

```
ID | items_bought
1        5
2        4
8        0
3        13
2        4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df1.groupby('ID').sum().loc[df2.ID].fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[104]: 
    items_bought
ID              
1              5
2              4
8              0
3             13
2              4
```

1. Work on df1 to calculate the sum for each `ID`.
2. The resulting dataframe is now indexed by `ID`, so you can select with `df2` IDs by calling `loc`.
3. Fill the gaps with `fillna`.
4. `NA` are handled by float type. Now that they are removed, convert the column back to integer.

Comment: When I do df2['items_bought'] = df1.groupby('ID')['items_bought'].sum().loc[df2.ID].fillna(0).astype(int) I get the error ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. Any idea why?

Comment: You have dupes in your ID column.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `groupby` and `sum`, then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `fill_value=0` and last `reset_index`:

```
df2 = df1.groupby('ID').items_bought.sum().reindex(df2.ID, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df2)
   ID  items_bought
0   1             5
1   2             4
2   8             0
3   3            13
4   2             4
```