# Pandas filling missing value from yesterday data (same DataTime) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to fill missing value by yesterday (one day back data) in python. for the same I am trying with following code but not getting expected output.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'input_3.csv')
saved_column = df.Value #you can also use df['column_name']


df['DateTime'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DateTime'])

b = df.loc[df.Value.isnull(), 'Value'] = \
              df.loc[df.Value.isnull(), 'Value'].map(df.loc[df.Value.notnull()] \
                .set_index('DateTime')['Value'])
print b
```

Yesterday's Data:

```
block   DateTime    Value
1   09-01-2016 00:00    -0.886492
2   09-01-2016 01:00    -0.500995
3   09-01-2016 02:00    4
4   09-01-2016 03:00    5
5   09-01-2016 04:00    2.145205
6   09-01-2016 05:00    0.475309
```

Today's Data:

```
1   10-01-2016 00:00    -0.886492
2   10-01-2016 01:00    -0.500995
3   10-01-2016 02:00    NaN
4   10-01-2016 03:00    NaN
5   10-01-2016 04:00    2.145205
6   10-01-2016 05:00    0.475309
```

Expected to fill today's data:

```
1   10-01-2016 00:00    -0.886492
2   10-01-2016 01:00    -0.500995
3   10-01-2016 02:00    5
4   10-01-2016 03:00    2.145205
5   10-01-2016 04:00    2.145205
6   10-01-2016 05:00    0.475309
```

Please suggest me some approach for the same. Thank you in advance

I have tried using this post [Fill values from one dataframe to another with matching IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941605/fill-values-from-one-dataframe-to-another-with-matching-ids) but not getting expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with another parameter `index_col`, `parse_dates` and `dayfirst=True` for `DatetimeIndex` first:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'input_3.csv', index_col=[1], parse_dates=[1], dayfirst=True)
print (df)
                     block     Value
DateTime                            
2016-01-09 00:00:00      1 -0.886492
2016-01-09 01:00:00      2 -0.500995
2016-01-09 02:00:00      3  4.000000
2016-01-09 03:00:00      4  5.000000
2016-01-09 04:00:00      5  2.145205
2016-01-09 05:00:00      6  0.475309
2016-01-10 00:00:00      1 -0.886492
2016-01-10 01:00:00      2 -0.500995
2016-01-10 02:00:00      3       NaN
2016-01-10 03:00:00      4       NaN
2016-01-10 04:00:00      5  2.145205
2016-01-10 05:00:00      6  0.475309
```

And then replace `NaN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed `datetime`s by one day:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].fillna(df.shift(freq='1d')['Value'])
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
              DateTime  block     Value
0  2016-01-09 00:00:00      1 -0.886492
1  2016-01-09 01:00:00      2 -0.500995
2  2016-01-09 02:00:00      3  4.000000
3  2016-01-09 03:00:00      4  5.000000
4  2016-01-09 04:00:00      5  2.145205
5  2016-01-09 05:00:00      6  0.475309
6  2016-01-10 00:00:00      1 -0.886492
7  2016-01-10 01:00:00      2 -0.500995
8  2016-01-10 02:00:00      3  4.000000
9  2016-01-10 03:00:00      4  5.000000
10 2016-01-10 04:00:00      5  2.145205
11 2016-01-10 05:00:00      6  0.475309
```